# Wf only valid in interpretation with domain of ≥ 4 elements

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a first-order language with two unary predicates $A^1_1$ and $A^1_2$. To have an interpretation $M$ of $\mathscr{L}$ that makes the well-formed formula (wf)

$$(\exists x₁)A^1_1(x₁) ∧ (\exists x₁)\neg A^1_1(x₁)
$$

true, it seems the only condition would be that the domain of $M$ has at least two elements. Now I am trying to find a wf that can only be true if the domain of the interpretation has at least *four* elements. Would the following do the trick?

$$(\exists x₁)A^1_1(x₁) ∧ (\exists x₁)\neg A^1_1(x₁) ∧ (\exists x_2)A^1_2(x_2) ∧ (\exists x₂)\neg A^1_2(x_2) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

No that wouldn't do the trick because it could be the same thing that e.g. both satisfies $A_1$ and $A_2$. So that wff is still satisfiable in any domain with at least two elements.

If you want to continue avoiding using the identity predicate, how about trying a conjunction with various clauses of the form $\exists x(?A_1x\ \land\ ?A_2x)$ where the ? is either empty or the negation sign ...

Comment: If you mean $(\exists x_1)(A^1_1(x_1) \wedge \neg A^1_2(x_1)) \wedge (\exists x_2)(\neg A^1_1(x_2) \wedge A^1_2(x_2)) \wedge (\exists x_3)(A^1_1(x_3) \wedge \neg A^1_2(x_3)) \wedge (\exists x_4)(\neg A^1_1(x_4) \wedge A^1_2(x_4))$, I think I get it :p

Comment: Apologies, I meant to use all permutations, so "Ø Ø, Ø ¬, ¬ Ø, ¬ ¬", if you see what I mean.